# Can the i7 980 be run in dual cpu motherboard?

Tags: cpu

I seem to have read somewhere that the i7 980 chip could be run on dual-socket motherboards, but I can't seem to find it. Can it ? My 980 needs a brother ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread [I7 980 microprocessor](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/281888-28-microprocessor) from Tom's Hardware says :

> i7 CPUs only have 1 QPI which allows
>   it to talk to the chipset. You need 2
>   QPIs so the CPU can talk to another
>   CPU and to the chipset. So no, **you can't use 2 980Xs in a motherboard**.
>
> Xeon 5500 (quad-core) or Xeon 5600
>   (hex-core) is what you'd need.